# Execute a block before each request in RestKit. Pre-request callback

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

Is there a way to tell **RestKit** to execute a block before each request. I'm thinking of a global pre-request callback.

I did something like this to provide a post request hook. I subclassed `RKManagedObjectRequestOperation` and overridden the `setCompletionBlockWithSuccess` function.

I checked the docs and can't find anything that would allow me to have a pre-request callback.
I might be missing something. Is it possible to do it using **RestKit** built-in functionalities?